# Merge Many excel files to one new file with different sheet

Tags: vba, merge, excel-2010

I am trying to merge many excel files (workbooks) from a folder. 
My problem is that I want to move different sheets to the new excel file. 
At the moment my code can only move one sheet at the time from these different files.

Example: 
I have 3 excel files named

- 1.xlsx
- 2.xlsx
- 3.xlsx

all 3 files have 3 sheets in it and I want to take sheet1 from 1.xlsx and sheet1 and sheet2 from 2.xlsx and finally sheet3 from 3.xlsx and put in a new excel file.

My code at the moment can only takes one sheet (and same sheet number) from each file and put in the new file.

My code so fare:

```
Sub MergeMultiSheets()
Dim wbDst As Workbook
Dim wbSrc As Workbook
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Dim Path As String
Dim Filename As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
path = "C:\Users\*ChangeThis*\Desktop\merge" 
Set wbDst = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
Filename = Dir(path & "\*.xlsx", vbNormal)

If Len(Filename) = 0 Then Exit Sub

Do Until Filename = ""
    Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & "\" & Filename)

    sheet = 1
    Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets(sheet)
    wsSrc.Copy After:=wbDst.Worksheets(wbDst.Worksheets.Count)

    wbSrc.Close False
    Filename = Dir()
Loop
wbDst.Worksheets(1).Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Many thank in advance

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: you must state the rule by which sheets are to be selected from all different files. in your example you gave the rule for 3 files each having 3 sheets: what if files are more (or less) than 3 and if any file has more (or less) than 3 sheets?

Comment: @user3598756 I see your point, but it was an example just so other would have an idea what I wanted with this.

Comment: @JessieQuick suit yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through all the Sheets in the current Workbook found in your folder.

Try the code below:

```
Sub MergeMultiSheets()

Dim wbDst As Workbook
Dim wbSrc As Workbook
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Dim Path As String
Dim Filename As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Path = "C:\Users\*ChangeThis*\Desktop\merge"    

Set wbDst = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
Filename = Dir(Path & "\*.xlsx", vbNormal)

If Len(Filename) = 0 Then Exit Sub

Do Until Filename = ""
    Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & "\" & Filename)

    Sheet = 1
    ' ****** you need to loop on all sheets per Excel workbook found in Folder ******
    For Each wsSrc In wbSrc.Sheets        
        wsSrc.Copy After:=wbDst.Worksheets(wbDst.Worksheets.Count)        
    Next wsSrc

    wbSrc.Close False
    Filename = Dir()
Loop
wbDst.Worksheets(1).Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: wsSrc.Copy After:=wbDst.Worksheets(wbDst.Worksheets.Count)   
Does this mean that it will copy after it have counted all the sheet in the differend workbook?

Comment: @JessieQuick it means it will copy it, and place this sheet at the end (order wise) of wbDst workbook

Comment: Thank alot for the help @Shai Rado